# Failed to compile. ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js , Module build failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I wanted to compile a vue project. However having following error:

```
here./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js (./node_modules/expose-loader/dist/cjs.js?$!./node_modules/expose-loader/dist/cjs.js?jQuery!./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js)
```

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/expose-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
at Object.loader (/Users/gi/mms-client/node_modules/expose-loader/dist/index.js:19:24)

This is the package json.

[image]

And the main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader? 
jQuery!jquery'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import i18n from './i18n'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
 i18n,
 render: h => h(App)
 }).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: ```import * as $ from 'jquery'```